# d3 geo - Map projection

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, projection, geo

With d3.geo, i want to draw a map with a projection that i do not want to find by try&error, but with a visual tool to help me along.

There is a tool out there: The [Visual Map Configurator](http://kartograph.org/showcase/editor/#ortho) for Kartograph.js.
Is there any tool i can use to generate a projection for d3.geo?

How do you find the projection you want, without try&error? I can get the origin parameters from any map but for scale and translate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While not as polished as Kartograph's configurator, if you clone the [D3 git repository](https://github.com/mbostock/d3), you'll find three examples with sliders to control the projection settings:

- [Albers](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/examples/albers/albers.html)
- [Azimuthal](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/examples/azimuthal/azimuthal.html)
- [Mercator](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/examples/mercator/mercator.html)

If you're using an azmithal projection, you can also try dragging [this interactive globe](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/azimuthal.html) and then use the JavaScript Console to extract the origin (`projection.origin()`).

Comment: See the [API reference for d3.geo.projection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections).